# Is deploying React app as part of Django application possible?

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I have django application that serves as backend and a multi page react app as frontend. I have bought one domain name and I want to deploy these app on that. I have a couple of questions,

1. Is it possible to deploy this which is catered by the single domain name? If possible how?
2. If yes then will this expose the backend APIs from django application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is possible to deploy both your Django backend and React frontend on a single domain name. One way to do this is to use subdomains for the two parts. For example, you can use [www.yourdomain.com](http://www.yourdomain.com) for the frontend and api.yourdomain.com for the backend. You can redirect from the subdomains to the respective hostings without changing your current hosting strategy